# Geoapify: how to determine if a location (latitude & longitude) lies inside isochrones returned by the Isoline API?

Tags: javascript, maps

I work for city government in the US and have built a demonstration page where job seekers can enter their address and see offices and other work locations within commuting distance of where they live. They can set travel mode and the maximum commute time.

I am using [Geoapify's Isoline API](https://apidocs.geoapify.com/docs/isolines/#about) to get "isochrones" ("iso" for equal; "chrone" for time as in "chronometer") and that works fine.

I have overlaid the isochrone(s) on top of a city map using the [Leaflet JS](https://leafletjs.com/) mapping tool with "markers" indicating all the city work locations. That works fine too.

What I need help with is how to identify which work locations lie inside the isochrone boundary (or boundaries), and which locations lie outside, so that I can apply different colors (using the filter: hue-rotate(_deg) trick noted elsewhere on StackOverflow) and exclude those locations from the job search results. Users can also click on markers to include/exclude particular locations.

I can't find anything in Geoapify's documentation for Isolines, or anything else, that tells me how to do that. I thought I might be able to use the "intersection" option in the [Geometry API](https://apidocs.geoapify.com/docs/geometry/#about) but that only works with polygons previously returned by Geoapify, not a previously returned polygon and an arbitrary point.

I also can't find anything useful elsewhere on the internet which surprises me since I thought determining whether a location is inside or outside a Geoapify polygon, or set of polygons, would be a common problem.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit 1: Here it is on CodePen:
https://codepen.io/PeterNotInPT/pen/jOXvEBj

Edit 2: The bot says I need to provide some code so...

I have an array of work locations:

```
const workLocations = [
    {address: "1100 4th St SW", checkBoxId: "1100_4th_St_SW", lat: 38.8779236210903, long: -77.01734764473007},
    {address: "901 G St NW (MLK Library)", checkBoxId: "901_G_St_NW", lat: 38.898857617145985, long: -77.02490318890965},
    {address: "200 I St SE", checkBoxId: "200_I_St_SE", lat: 38.88009836346278, long: -77.00301703123823},
    {address: "250 M St SE", checkBoxId: "250_M_St_SE", lat: 38.87710278028664, long: -77.00228744473007},
    {address: "1200 First St NE", checkBoxId: "1200_1st_St NE", lat: 38.9062224010956, long: -77.00633570240119},
    {address: "401 E St SW", checkBoxId: "401_E_St_SW", lat: 38.88384810576917, long: -77.01837154472987},
    {address: "5171 S. Dakota Ave NE", checkBoxId: "5171_S_Dakota_Ave_NE", lat: 38.953866767991535, long: -76.99689878892342},
    {address: "4058 Minnesota Ave NE", checkBoxId: "4058_Minnesota_Ave_NE", lat: 38.8972271711626, long: -76.94782147356544},
    {address: "64 New York Ave NE", checkBoxId: "64_New_York_Ave NE", lat: 38.909404103508585, long: -77.00682069859793},
    {address: "441 4th St NW", checkBoxId: "441_4th_St_NW", lat: 38.89557803243445, long: -77.01559446369988},
    {address: "250 E St SW", checkBoxId: "250_E_St_SW", lat: 38.88308925938507, long: -77.01442327356588},
    {address: "899 N Capitol St NE", checkBoxId: "899_N_Capitol_St_NE", lat: 38.90122286178571, long: -77.00851884472931},
    {address: "300 Indiana Ave NW", checkBoxId: "300_Indiana_Ave_NW", lat: 38.89434842828109, long: -77.01654850240159},
    {address: "450 H St NW", checkBoxId: "450_H_St_NW", lat: 38.8996997262375, long: -77.01834512531399},
    {address: "1350 Pennsylvania Ave NW", checkBoxId: "1350_Pennsylvania_Ave_NW", lat: 38.89524892650393, long: -77.0311579735655},
    {address: "100 M St SE", checkBoxId: "100_M_St_SE", lat: 38.87693687601847, long: -77.00543590240223},
    {address: "1000 Mt Olivet Rd NE", checkBoxId: "1000_Mt_Olivet_Rd_NE", lat: 38.912293364817415, long: -76.98856784061661},
    {address: "1015 Half St SE", checkBoxId: "1015_Half_St_SE", lat: 38.878250824689125, long: -77.00787066007439},
    {address: "1050 1st St NE", checkBoxId: "1050_1st_St_NE", lat: 38.90351025490712, long: -77.00626776007343},
    {address: "4665 Blue Plains Dr SW (Police Academy)", checkBoxId: "4665_Blue_Plains_Dr_SW", lat: 38.82174895414032, long: -77.01337855584724},
    {address: "2000 14th St NW", checkBoxId: "2000_14th_St_NW", lat: 38.91751656148031, long: -77.03237447356476},
    {address: "1133 15th St NW", checkBoxId: "1133_15th_St_NW", lat: 38.90504625093286, long: -77.0340116735652},
    {address: "1325 G St NW", checkBoxId: "1325_G_St_NW", lat: 38.898638267512005, long: -77.03104443123755},
    {address: "2720 Martin Luther King Jr SE (St. Elizabeths Hospital)", checkBoxId: "2720_Martin_Luther_King_Jr_SE", lat: 38.853848229101054, long: -76.9951069305929},
    {address: "3924 Minnesota Ave NE", checkBoxId: "3924_Minnesota_Ave_NE", lat: 38.89411232957772, long: -76.95144373123782},
    {address: "515 5th st NW", checkBoxId: "515_5th_St_NW", lat: 38.896895522050734, long: -77.01835873123757},
    {address: "655 15th St NW", checkBoxId: "655_15th_St_NW", lat: 38.89808214620608, long: -77.03307029705881},
    {address: "2001 E. Capitol St (DC Armory)", checkBoxId: "2001_E_Capitol_St", lat: 38.88910535380775, long: -76.97550222355162},
    {address: "1901 D St SE (Detention Facility)", checkBoxId: "1901_D_St_SE", lat: 38.883812015891536, long: -76.97599977044904}
];
```

Getting the base map using the Leaflet mapping library and adding the work locations to that map:

```
let lastIsochrone;
let lastMarker;
let map; 

const drawBaseMap = function() {
    map = L.map('map').setView([centerDC.lat, centerDC.long], zoom);

    // Retina displays require different mat tiles quality
    var isRetina = L.Browser.retina;

    var baseUrl = `https://maps.geoapify.com/v1/tile/osm-bright/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apiKey=${apiKey}`;
    var retinaUrl = `https://maps.geoapify.com/v1/tile/osm-bright/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png?apiKey=${apiKey}`;

    // Tiles
    L.tileLayer(isRetina ? retinaUrl : baseUrl, {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        maxZoom: 20,
        id: 'osm-bright',
    }).addTo(map);

    /* I intended to call addWorkLocationsToMap() from the initialize method but there is a scope problem because Leaflet
    is creating a variable 't' and even though 'map' is a global variable, 't' is not so there is an 'undefined' error.
    I also tried passing 'L' that is apparently global but that did not help so dumping contents of that method here.
    I'll try again later. */
    let markerLocations =[];
    workLocations.forEach(function (location, index) {
        markerLocations[index] = L.marker([location.lat, location.long], {title: location.address}).addTo(map);
        markerLocations[index]._icon.classList.add("green");
        markerLocations[index]._icon.setAttribute("linkedchkbox", location.checkBoxId);

        markerLocations[index].addEventListener("click", function(e){
            let linkedChkBoxID = markerLocations[index]._icon.getAttribute("linkedchkbox");
            let linkedChkBox = document.getElementById(linkedChkBoxID);
            markerLocations[index]._icon.classList.toggle("green");
            markerLocations[index]._icon.classList.toggle("red");

            if(markerLocations[index]._icon.classList.contains("green")) {
                linkedChkBox.checked = true;
                linkedChkBox.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
            }
            else {
                linkedChkBox.checked = false;
                linkedChkBox.removeAttribute("checked");
            }

            // POST to https://careers.dc.gov/psc/erecruit/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM_FL.HRS_CG_SEARCH_FL.GBL
            // Current page uses fake checkboxes with ID PTS_SELECT$chk$<index>
        });
    });

};
```

and then finally adding the "isochrone" from Geoapify, the area in which the user can travel within the time they specify using their desired mode of travel

```
const getCommuterMap = function(startAddress) {
    warningNotice.classList.add("hidden");
    const encodedAddressText = encodeURI(startAddress);
    var getAddressDetailsUrl = `https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/search?text=${encodedAddressText}&format=json&apiKey=${apiKey}&filter=circle:${centerDC.long},${centerDC.lat},${searchRadius}`;

    fetch(getAddressDetailsUrl, {
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(response => {
        if(response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        else {
            displayErrorMsg("Invalid server response. Status code: " + response.status + " (" + response.statusText +")");
        }
    })
    .then(data => {
            if(data.results && ["building", "amenity"].includes(data.results[0].result_type) && data.results[0].rank.confidence > 0.95) {
                var addressInfo =  {lat: data.results[0].lat, lon: data.results[0].lon, addressLine1: data.results[0].address_line1};
                var transitMode = getTransitMode();
                var maxCommuteTime = getMaxCommuteTime();
                addStartMarkerToMap(addressInfo);
                addIsochroneToMap(addressInfo, transitMode, maxCommuteTime * 60);
            }
            else {
                displayErrorMsg("Sorry, the address '" + data.query.text + "' was not recognized.");
            }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        displayErrorMsg(error);
    });
};

const addStartMarkerToMap = function(addressInfo) {
    lastMarker = L.marker([addressInfo.lat, addressInfo.lon], {title: addressInfo.addressLine1}).addTo(map);
};

const addIsochroneToMap = function(addressInfo, transitMode, range) {
    fetch(`https://api.geoapify.com/v1/isoline?lat=${addressInfo.lat}&lon=${addressInfo.lon}&type=time&mode=${transitMode}&range=${range}&apiKey=${apiKey}`)
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(geoJSONFeatures => {
        lastIsochrone = L.geoJSON(geoJSONFeatures, {
            style: (feature) => {
                return {
                    stroke: true,
                    color: '#9933ff',
                    weight: 2,
                    opacity: 0.7,
                    fill: true,
                    fillColor: '#333399',
                    fillOpacity: 0.15,
                    smoothFactor: 0.5,
                    interactive: false
                };
            }
        }).addTo(map);
    });
};
```

Finally, the styles for the locations markers on the map. I want to make those inside the isochrone green, and those outside red. The problem is that I don't know how to tell which location markers are inside the isochrone.

```
<style>
    .red { filter: hue-rotate(150deg); }
    .green { filter: hue-rotate(270deg); }
</style>
```

Edit 3: It looks like I can implement by own solution using the information here:
http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in Edit 3 above, the way to determine if a point is inside a polygon is detailed in http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/. However, the Geoapify data may contain "enclaves" - polygons within polygons - so I had to jump through some extra hoops to handle that.

Note that the Geoapify data returns a point as [longitude, latitude], whereas if you right-click on Google Maps, the top option is the coordinate expressed as "latitude, longitude" which is the way we usually speak about it. I initially had some of my code using latitude when it needed longitude and vice versa.

Two new functions:

```
const locationIsInsidePolygon = function(location, polygon) { // Polygon may be an "enclave" within an outer polygon!
    //  From http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/ (written in C, not Javascript)
    //  The function will return true if the point x,y is inside the polygon, or false if it is not.
    let i;
    let j = polygon.length - 1;
    let numberOfNodesIsOdd = false;

    for (i = 0; i < polygon.length; i++) {
    //for (i=0; i<polyCorners; i++) {

        if((polygon[i][1] < location.lat && polygon[j][1] >= location.lat) || 
           (polygon[j][1] < location.lat && polygon[i][1] >= location.lat)) {

            if(polygon[i][0] + (location.lat - polygon[i][1]) / (polygon[j][1] - polygon[i][1]) * (polygon[j][0] - polygon[i][0]) < location.lon) {
                numberOfNodesIsOdd =! numberOfNodesIsOdd;
            }
        }
        j=i; 
    }

    return numberOfNodesIsOdd;              
};


const updateWorkLocationMarkers = function(responseObj) {
    /*
    The response from Geoapify contains features -> geometry -> coordinates which is an array of arrays of arrays.
    The top-level contans one element for each isochrone which is represented by a "blob" on the map.
    However, there can be "enclaves" within blobs that a user can't reach within the travel time specified.
    If there are enclaves, the first of the second-level arrays is the "outer" polygon, then subsequent elements 
    are the "enclaves". If there are no enclaves, there is a single array element at the second level.
    Third-level elements are the longitude/latitude points for each corner of the polygon.
    */
    const topLevelArrayElements = responseObj.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
    let secondLevelArrayElements;
    let isInsideTravelZone;
    let isInsidePolygon;
    let isEnclave;
    let i, j;

    workLocations.forEach(function (location, index) {
        markerLocation = {lat: location.lat, lon: location.long};

        isInsideTravelZone = false;
        isEnclave = false;

        for(i=0; i < topLevelArrayElements.length; i++) {
            secondLevelArrayElements = topLevelArrayElements[i];
            isEnclave = false;
            //hasEnclaves = secondLevelArrayElements.length == 1 ? false : true;

            for(j=0; j < secondLevelArrayElements.length; j++) {
                if(j > 0) {
                    isEnclave = true;
                }
                isInsidePolygon = locationIsInsidePolygon(markerLocation, secondLevelArrayElements[j]);
                if(isInsidePolygon) {
                    if(isEnclave){
                        isInsideTravelZone = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        isInsideTravelZone = true; // May be reset to false if there are enclaves.
                    }
                }
            }

            if(isInsideTravelZone) {
                break; // No need to test other isoclines/polygons
            }
        }

        setMarkerAsInsideSearchArea(index, isInsideTravelZone ? true : false);
    });
};
```

and at the second method is called at the bottom of addIsochroneToMap, immediately after `.addTo(map);`

```
updateWorkLocationMarkers(geoJSONFeatures);
```

Demonstration page: https://codepen.io/PeterNotInPT/pen/MWZzKgP